# How to use Traceback and debug to fix broken R code?

Tags: r, function, debugging, text-mining, traceback

I'm trying to write a script that simplifies the process of producing a clean corpus from a vector or data frame for text mining and NLP.  However, my script produces an error when I run it.  My script is as follows:

```
  quick_clean <- function(data, Vector = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                     stop.words = NULL, ...) {
  if(Vector == TRUE) {
    source <- VectorSource(data)
  } else {
    source <- DataframeSource(data)
  }
  corp <- VCorpus(source)
  corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)

  if(removePunctuation == TRUE) {
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
  }
  if(removeNumbers == TRUE) {
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
  }
  if(is.null(stop.words)) {
   return(corp)
  } else {
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, c(stopwords("en"), stop.words))
  }
  corp
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I ran the traceback, but I'm not really sure how to use this information:

```
7. get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) 
6. match.fun(FUN) 
5. lapply(X, FUN, ...) 
4. tm_parLapply(content(x), FUN, ...) 
3. tm_map.VCorpus(corp, removePunctuation) 
2. tm_map(corp, removePunctuation) 
1. quick_clean(swift_vec)
```

I also ran Debug and got the following...again, I'm not sure how to use this info:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
Called from: get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)
Browse[1]>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It could be because you are using the name `source` as a variable. Its a problem because `source` is also a function name in R. Change that to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine the `traceback` pile from the bottom:

1. your error is in `quick_clean`
2. it's on the `corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)` line, luckily you only have one
3. inside `tm_map` the function itself is calling the method `tm_map.VCorpus`, as your corp object is of class `Vcorpus` and tm_map is a wrapper for different methods
4. This function itself is calling `tm_parLapply` etc...

From the time you hit a reliable function in `traceback` it's usually not so useful to go much further, it means that the input you gave to the functions isn't good.

We learnt that you gave a `Vcorpus` object as a first parameter, so this one seems to be ok, though we may check later if its format is not problematic.

But let's check the other parameter, `removePunctuation`, the doc (`?tm_map`) says it requires a function, if you use `debug`, `debugonce` or `browser` (look them up). you'll see that their boolean at the time you execute the line.

And they're boolean because you named your function parameters just like those functions.

So rename your function parameters and hopefully it will run fine :).

***here's how you may use `browser`:***

define this function (spot the added line)

```
quick_clean <- function(data, Vector = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                     stop.words = NULL, ...) {
  if(Vector == TRUE) {
    source <- VectorSource(data)
  } else {
    source <- DataframeSource(data)
  }
  corp <- VCorpus(source)
  corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)

  if(removePunctuation == TRUE) {
    browser() # <----------------------------------------- here !
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
  }
  if(removeNumbers == TRUE) {
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
  }
  if(is.null(stop.words)) {
   return(corp)
  } else {
    corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, c(stopwords("en"), stop.words))
  }
  corp
}
```

Execute the line that triggered the error
type `class(corp)` to confirm what we already know
type `class(removePunctuation)`
Ooops, it's a boolean.
Type `Q` or the escape key to get out of the browser.

`debug` is like `browser`, but starts at the first line of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your response I changed my parameters, e.g. `removePunctuation` is now `remove.Punctuation` but it's still telling me there's a problem with this line of code. However, this, I think has really moved my understand forward in that I should never make argument names the same as functions names.  Now, when you said to "execute the line that triggered the error", do you mean just that line with the `browse()` function there or run the entire script?

Comment: make sure none of your variable names are names of function, and chooses names that are not confusing, such as `rem_punct_bool`, do it for `removeNumbers `, `source`, `stop.words`, then if you can still not identify the error, paste your new function and traceback as an edit at the end of your post